# How to open a PDF file using a third-party application (intent, url)

Tags: android, pdf, url, provider

```
       int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
    } else {
        File file = new File("/sdcard/reportSituationAddress.pdf");
        if (file.exists()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider" ,file);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(Pdftest.this, "No Application available to view pdf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Pdftest.this, "not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

I have a pdf file, I need to open it at the click of a button. So that the user after clicking could select the application to open the file, and then the file would open in it. I use the provider, but constantly get errors. Please help solve the problem.

Its my fileprovider

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/telros.brigade/files/Pictures" />
    <external-files-path name="name" path="AisBrigade/Pdf" />
</paths>
```

Its my manifest

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:authorities="ru.npobaltros.aisbrigade.mapsdk.storage.workmanager-init_new"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:replace="android:authorities" />
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="telros.brigade"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

It should be like this, only programs to open pdf.
[image]

My errors
[image]

Maybe someone has a piece of working code, where it is implemented, if so, please show

Comment: hey did you ever find a solution for this.  Experiencing the same problem and can't seem to find a straight answer on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an entry in your `FileProvider` metadata that covers your chosen path.

First, stop hard-coding paths. Use methods to assemble a path from a root location. My guess is that you think that your PDF is in the root of [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html). In that case, you would use:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "reportSituationAddress.pdf");
```

Then, ensure that your `FileProvider` metadata supports your root location. For `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, [use `<external-path>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider#SpecifyFiles).

Also, note that [you have very little filesystem access on Android 10 and higher](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html). For example, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is deprecated on Android 10, as by default you do not have access to it.

Comment: I fixed how you said "file". 
But my FileProvider: <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/telros.brigade/files/Pictures" />
    <external-files-path name="name" path="AisBrigade/Pdf" />

</paths>
And I still have the same error